# A problem based on counting in Quantitative aptitude

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

This question was asked by my younger brother and I could not solve it.

Image->[image]

I tried it by listing all inequalities but could not get how can I solve it.

> Answer is A.

Comment: *Answer is A* That´s right. See the answers of the linked questions.

Comment: The question is **very** badly worded. Apparently the statement ‘$a_2$ number of fishermen caught at least two fish among them’ is supposed to be interpreted as ‘there were $a_2$ fishermen who each caught at least two fish’, though in standard English it actually means something quite different, namely, that there was a group of $a_2$ fishermen whose combined catch was at least two fish. With that reinterpretation this does become the linked question, which is correctly stated. In this version the question is more a matter of guessing the author’s intent than of working out the mathematics.